# Identifying a potential Greengage Plum tree

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, plums

We think that this is a plum tree, but we are not 100% sure and just wanted to confirm that there aren't any poisonous look-alikes out there before we taste one. From the small size of the fruit we think that they might be Greengage plum trees. The trees are in the backyard of our house in the foothills of the Sierra Nevada in Northern California. Any confirmation or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to see if they sell Greengage somewhere, and try to taste a sample to compare with yours.

Comment: I personally never heard of anything poisonous that looks so much like a plum. This tree could be a specific named variety - maybe Greengage, but if it grew from a spit-out seed, it could be a "mutt". They come in all sorts of colors & sizes, some sweet, some tart, some sour, some delicious. Some little, and some really little. And just like dogs, some of the most loyal plums are mutts. Judging from the size of your crop, it seems like you have a very faithful companion there.